# Is there a way to 'mov eax, ax'?

Tags: x86, nasm

I would like to move my return from `htons` call `00005c11` and have have moved to the top if `eax` and have the result of `5c110000`.

Nasm won't let me `mov eax, ax` due to size constraints. Is there a defined way to do this or a potential hack?

Comment: movzx eax, ax should work and is arguably easier to understand than the rotate-left solution, because it more clearly communicates intent.

Comment: +1 IMHO, `movzx eax, ax` is more natural.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is to use `rol`:

```
rol eax, 10
```